# OpenVPN: routing to two VPNs

Tags: routing, openvpn, linux-networking, multiple-instances

Using Ubuntu 14.04 (up to date).

I'd like to use two VPNs (openvpn) a the same time.
LAN is: **`10.1.1.0/24`**

The 1st VPN, homemade, is only routing the **`192.168.1.0/24`** network via the tunnel.

**Routes table before VPN1 is started**

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.1.1.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.1.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
```

**Routes table after VPN1 is started**

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.1.1.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.14.0.0       10.14.0.2       255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.14.0.2       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
10.1.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.88.0.1       10.88.0.5       255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun1
10.88.0.5       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     10.88.0.5       255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun1
```

The problem is after starting the 2nd VPN (from PIA), which installs a default route, the `192.168.1.0` subnet is not routed anymore. (The rest is working).

For instance, doing a ping to `192.168.1.1` works fine until the 2nd VPN becomes active.

**Routes table after VPN2 is started**

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.182.1.5      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun2
0.0.0.0         10.1.1.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.14.0.0       10.14.0.2       255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.14.0.2       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
10.1.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.88.0.1       10.88.0.5       255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun1
10.88.0.5       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun1
10.182.1.1      10.182.1.5      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun2
10.182.1.5      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun2
128.0.0.0       10.182.1.5      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun2
161.202.72.156  10.1.1.1        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     10.88.0.5       255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun1
```

However, and this is what I don't understand, the `192.168.1.0` route is still alive, and is way more specific than the default routes. There doesn't seem to be any conflicting internal openvpn tunnel routes.

Is this `192.168.1.0` routing problem fixable, having the two VPNs running at the same time?